# partial url needs JWT authentication on slim 3 php framework

Tags: php, slim

I have most everything working with JWT authentication with tuupola/slim-jwt-auth. One thing i am not sure what to do is partial URL authorization.

lets say I have the public URLs

```
 www.xyz.com/api/v1/products
 www.xyz.com/api/v1/products/123
```

Then I have a sub URL need authorization only for /internal

```
 www.xyz.com/api/v1/products/123/internal
```

In middlewares, I have:

```
 $jwt = new \Slim\Middleware\JwtAuthentication([
    "path" => ["/api", "/other"],
    "passthrough" => ["/api/v1/products", "/other/urls"],
    //more settings....
]);

$app->add($jwt);
```

so my question is: how can I only secure the /api/v1/products/123/internal

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `path` setting you set the path with should be authenticated. To authenticate everything starting with `/api/v1/products/123/internal` you can do the following.

```
$jwt = new \Slim\Middleware\JwtAuthentication([
    "path" => ["/api/v1/products/123/internal"]
]);

$app->add($jwt);
```

However it is not clear from your question but I have a feeling you actually want to authenticate product with any id and not just 123. To achieve this you can use a regexp.

```
$jwt = new \Slim\Middleware\JwtAuthentication([
    "path" => ["/api/v1/products/(\d*)/internal"]
]);

$app->add($jwt);
```

Comment: Thanks Mika, this is exactly what I need, and you corrected my misunderstanding too. Cheers.